# cmake : shared library : how to get the .lib name instead of .dll name?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, cmake

Under Windows, with cmake I generate a shared library and an executable.

The shared lib generate 2 files, a .DLL and a .LIB

I use `add_custom_command` with `$<TARGET_FILE:mylibname>`, this output the name of the .DLL file.

But, I need the name of the .LIB file.

How can I do ? Any idea ?

Comment: `$<TARGET_LINKER_FILE:tgt>`?

Comment: Just know that Cmake does not want you to use these things and they may have unexpected values in unexpected situations. If you need these, you're probably going at it the wrong way

Answer (score 2):

Just found how, maybe it will be useful for someone else, so I share.

Simply use TARGET_LINKER_FILE instead of TARGET_FILE !